# Swift run function before collectionView's functions

Tags: ios, swift

I have got this function in my swift code

```
  func myFunc(){
     let jsonData2 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [[String: Any]
     self.comments = jsonData2
  }
```

And in collectionView's `numberOfItemsInSection` function i have this

```
return comments.count
```

What i need is to first run `myFunc` and after that run all other collectionView's functions.I tried putting `myFunc()` right at the begginning of `viewDidLoad()`,but it didn't worked.

Comment: don't add `collectionview delegate and datasource` connection with xib or storyboard. Assign delegate and datasource after `myfunc()` completes and then reload Collectionview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need define your `comments` array as empty, and then load your relevant data in your viewWillAppear

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
      var comments : [YourObjects] = []

     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.myFunc()
      }

    func myFunc(){
         let jsonData2 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [[String: Any]
         self.comments = jsonData2
         DispatchQueue.main.async{
          self.collectionView.reloadData() //reload data after
         }   
      }

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you,it works but it gives something in violet box like error `UICollectionView.reloadData() must be called from main thread only`

Comment: Then you need add some code i will update my answer its wierd because viewWillAppear is called in main thread

Comment: Thanks for thy help!

Answer (score 1):

Try place it in `viewWillAppear(_:)` method and call `reloadData()` after `comments` array has changed.

Comment: in `override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) `?

Comment: Yes. You can also place it in your custom `init` as well.

Comment: i tried putting it in init and viewillappear,but again `numberOfItemsInSection` got called first in both shots

Comment: Have you tried to call `reloadData()` after `comments` array has changed (even if you call `myFunc()` in `viewDidLoad()`)?

Comment: Thank you `reloadData()` worked,but it printed a lot of things in console i hope they are not errors

Comment: please edit your answer to reloadData thus i can accept it

Answer (score 1):

You should use reload data to update `UICollectionView`'s content

```
  func myFunc(){
     let jsonData2 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [[String: Any]
     self.comments = jsonData2
     self.collectionView.reloadData()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make sure that `comments` is initialized before first use is to use a lazy property:

```
lazy var comments: [String:Any] = self.myFunc()

func myFunc() -> [String:Any] {
    return try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data()) as! [String:Any]
}
```